Error 'Cannot find module' while testing react appliation using component react-markdown
I created simple react app contening notes using react-markdown component. Application works  but my tests gives error
Cannot find module 'unist-util-visit-parents/do-not-use-color' from 'node_modules/unist-util-visit-parents/lib/index.js'   

Require stack:
  node_modules/unist-util-visit-parents/lib/index.js
  node_modules/unist-util-visit-parents/index.js
  node_modules/unist-util-visit/lib/index.js
  node_modules/unist-util-visit/index.js
  node_modules/mdast-util-to-hast/lib/state.js
  node_modules/mdast-util-to-hast/lib/index.js
  node_modules/mdast-util-to-hast/index.js
  node_modules/remark-rehype/index.js
  node_modules/react-markdown/lib/index.js
  node_modules/react-markdown/index.js
  src/Note.tsx
  src/Note.test.tsx

Note.tsx code is following:
    import { Badge, Button, Col, Row, Stack } from "react-bootstrap";
    import { useNote } from "./NoteWrapper";
    import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
    import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";

    type NoteProps = {
        onDelete: (id: string) => void
    }

    export function Note({ onDelete }: NoteProps) {
        const note = useNote()
        const navigate = useNavigate()

        return <>
            <Row className="align-items-center mb-4">
                <Col>
                    <h1>{note.title}</h1>
                    {note.tags.length > 0 && (
                        <Stack gap={1} direction="horizontal" className="justify-context-center flex-wrap">
                            {note.tags.map(tag => (
                                <Badge className="text-truncate" key={tag.id}>
                                    {tag.label}
                                </Badge>
                            ))}
                        </Stack>
                    )}
                </Col>
                <Col sx="auto" >
                    <Stack gap={2} direction="horizontal">
                        <Link to={`/${note.id}/edit`}>
                            <Button variant="primary">Edit</Button>
                        </Link>
                        <Button onClick={() => {
                            onDelete(note.id)
                            navigate('..')
                        }}
                            variant="outline-danger">Delete</Button>
                        <Link to="..">
                            <Button variant="outline-secondary">Back</Button>
                        </Link>
                    </Stack>
                </Col>
            </Row >
            <ReactMarkdown>{note.markdown}</ReactMarkdown>
        </>
    }

Test looks like this:
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Note } from './Note';
import { useNote } from './NoteWrapper';

jest.mock('./NoteWrapper', () => ({
  useNote: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('Note Component', () => {
  const mockNote = {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Test Note',
    tags: [
      { id: 'tag1', label: 'Tag1' },
      { id: 'tag2', label: 'Tag2' },
    ],
    markdown: 'This is a test note.',
  };

  const mockOnDelete = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    (useNote as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue(mockNote);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test('renders note title and tags', () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Note onDelete={mockOnDelete} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(screen.getByText('Test Note')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('Tag1')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('Tag2')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test('calls onDelete when delete button is clicked', () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Note onDelete={mockOnDelete} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    // Simulate delete button click
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Delete'));

    // Check if onDelete was called with the correct id
    expect(mockOnDelete).toHaveBeenCalledWith('1');
  });
});


Have you tried running npm i?

application works, it's only problem when running tests. I can add this package and try to install it.

Are you using the latest 9.0.1 of react-markdown? I checked and beore this version, it relied on deps via deep imports that wont work in modern node as they had missing ESM export maps. Note 9.0.0 is no good. Needs to be absolute latest  9.0.1. Try npm install --save react-markdown@latest to bump it.
